# Is there a way to populate an Amazon DynamoDB table from a CloudFormation template?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I need to create a DynamoDB table were one of the attribute values its passed as a parameter in a CloudFormation template:

The DynamoDB table should look like this:

```
PhoneNumber     |       OrderNumber

223546421               11545154
784578745               11547854
223458784               11547487
XXXXXXXXX               11578451
```

The attribute value "XXXXXXXXX" needs to be passed as a parameter from a CloudFormation template were the DynamoDB table is going to be created and populated with the information above.

This is the current CF template which builds the DynamoDB table:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "OrdersTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties": {
                "TableName": "ClientOrders",
                "AttributeDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "PhoneNumber",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "OrderNumber",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    }
                ],
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "PhoneNumber",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "OrderNumber",
                        "KeyType": "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                "TimeToLiveSpecification": {
                    "AttributeName": "ExpirationTime",
                    "Enabled": true
                },
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "10",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "DynamoDBQueryPolicy"
            ]
        },
        "DynamoDBQueryPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": "DynamoDBQueryPolicy",
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "dynamodb:Query",
                            "Resource": "*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "OrdersTableQueryRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "OrdersTableQueryRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need help to populate the table with the mentioned values above and how to pass mentioned attribute value as a parameter.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is now a way to specify an "import source specification": see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-table-importsourcespecification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need [custom cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) resource to add entries into Dynamo Table.

From Docs:

> With Lambda functions and custom resources, you can run custom code in
> response to stack events (create, update, and delete).

> This custom resource invokes a Lambda function and sends it the StackName property as input. The function uses this property to get outputs from the appropriate stack.

Here is a sample I created for 1 key, need some minor changes:

We need two things.

One, a stack which holds the Lambda function. With this we not have a cloudformation resource which calls this Lambda behind the scenes when we add/remove/update a resource. This typically goes into separate stack all together.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
    DynamoCfnLambdaRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - lambda.amazonaws.com
                      Action:
                          - sts:AssumeRole
            Path: '/'
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: dynamodbAccessRole
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - dynamodb:*
                            Resource: '*'
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - logs:*
                            Resource: '*'
    CfnCrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: 'cfn-crt-upd-dlt-dynamodb-document'
            Code:
                ZipFile: >
                    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
                    const response = require("./cfn-response");
                    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
                    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
                      var item = JSON.parse(event.ResourceProperties.DynamoItem);
                      var keyProperty = event.ResourceProperties.DynamoKeyProperty;
                      var tableName = event.ResourceProperties.DynamoTableName;
                      if (event.RequestType == "Create" || event.RequestType == "Update") {
                        console.log("item:", item);
                        var params = {
                          TableName: tableName,
                          Item: item
                        };
                        console.log("Creating or Updating Document");
                        docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {                
                          if (err) {
                            console.log('error creating/updating document', err);
                            response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {}, tableName + '_' + item[keyProperty]);
                          } else {
                            response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {}, tableName + '_' + item[keyProperty]);
                          }
                        });
                      }

                      if (event.RequestType == "Delete") {
                        console.log("Deleting a Document");
                        var params = {
                          TableName: tableName,
                          Key: {
                            [keyProperty]: item[keyProperty]
                          }
                        };
                        docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
                          if (err) {
                            response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {});
                          } else {
                            response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {});
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    };
            Handler: index.handler
            Role: !GetAtt DynamoCfnLambdaRole.Arn
            Runtime: nodejs10.x
            Timeout: 60
```

Second, we need to add resource blocks `Custom::ThisCouldBeAnything` with `ServiceToken` pointing to Lambda Arn we created above. Whenever we

- Add a new block in any cloudformation, Lambda will be called with Create, which creates an entry in to Dynamo table.
- Remove the block from Cloudformation, Lambda will be called with Delete, which delete entry from Dynamo Table.
- Change something in resource block, example change something in DynamoItem, Lambda will be called with Update.

We need one resource block for every record that we need to insert into Dynamo.

```
Resources:
    MyPhone223546421:
        Type: Custom::CrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda
        Properties:
            ServiceToken: !GetAtt CfnCrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda.Arn
            DynamoTableName: My-Table
            DynamoKeyProperty: 'PhoneNumber'
            DynamoItem: |
                {
                  "PhoneNumber": "223546421",
                  "OrderNumber": "11545154",
                  "someKey": "someValue"
                }
    MyPhone784578745:
        Type: Custom::CrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda
        Properties:
            ServiceToken: !GetAtt CfnCrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda.Arn
            DynamoTableName: My-Table
            DynamoKeyProperty: 'PhoneNumber'
            DynamoItem: |
                {
                  "PhoneNumber": "784578745",
                  "OrderNumber": "11547854",
                  "someKey": "someValue"
                }
```

Comment: How do you specify in the custom telephone number resources that they are `event.RequestType == "Create"` ?

Comment: I didn't follow the question fully. given example is we are passing the entire document which needs to be inserted into dynamo as `DynamoItem` and keyName itself is passed to `DynamoKeyProperty` as PhoneNumber. Lambda code is doing put, which creates/updates by key which is PhoneNumber in this case.

Comment: How does the Lambda know its Create or Update, how does this condition get satisfied: `if (event.RequestType == "Create" || event.RequestType == "Update")`

Comment: when you add a new block to cloudformation ex: MyPhone784578745 , then lambda is called with create. If you remove the entire block , lambda is called with Delete, if you change something in resource , lambda is called with update.

Comment: In your case, you have 4 records to be inserted in to Dynamo table, so, you need to add 4 resource blocks. (like 2 blocks I gave). when you add those resource blocks 4 records will be added to dynamo. when you remove those blocks , 4 records will be deleted from Dynamo.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Thanks for the complete response. I'm still in doubt regarding how to properly use custom cloudformation resource. The first part would be the custom CF resource template that i'm going to call from the main CF template. The last part that you mentioned how we can use it, should be added to the main CF as well. Could you provide a little bit more of detail to mark the response as valid? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GabrielGuiridlian I added some more details. Thanks.

Comment: what is `const response = require("./cfn-response");` ?

Comment: do we have _types_ (`typescript`) for that **event**? you _know_ that the event has `RequestType` and `ResourceProperties`, but how do you know it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way, natively, to add rows to a DynamoDB table via CloudFormation. CloudFormation is a tool designed to create/manage infrastructure, not data. I would recommend doing that in a separate process. For example, if you are deploying via CodePipeline you could have a CodeBuild job that runs after the CloudFormation is created. That code can do just about anything you want it to do.

There is the option of creating either a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or a [resource provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/resource-types.html), but while it would be possible I don't think this is within its intended purpose.